# Laravel - Display my array images in view that is stored in one ROW in my Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, laravel

[image]I want to display all of my images that is displayed on my database in one ROW. The images are stores in an array in my database so it is in one ROW. Currently in my code the image is not showing and it is UNAVAILABLE

Here is my ***CONTROLLER***

***Storing Data***

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'promotion_image' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->has('promotion_image'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload

        $promotion = [];
        foreach ($request->file('promotion_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/promotion_images',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($promotion, $fileNameToStore);
        }

        $fileNameToStore = serialize($promotion);
    }
    else
    {
        $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
    }


if (count($promotion)) {
        $implodedPromotion = implode(' , ', $promotion);
        $promotionImage = new Promotion;
        $promotionImage->promotion_image = $implodedPromotion;
        $promotionImage->save();

        return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions')->with('success', 'Image Inserted');
    }

    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions')->with('error', 'Something went wrong.');
```

Here is my ***VIEW***

```
 @foreach($promotions as $promotion)
           <tr>  

            <th><img src="{{ asset('storage/promotion_images/' . $promotion->promotion_image) }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"></th>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Check your console. It will show the Image URL that couldn't load. According to that URL you need to modify the image path. Can you show you console Error please?

Comment: Please see the new edit. I added the problem .. there is no error just the image are not showing

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar I Edit the question above please see the image .. It has no error, my problem is that the images are not showing

Comment: The error only shows in console. you should check your path. Right-Click on image and click on `Open Image in New Tab` then show the image URL, And also show the directory tree.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar I did that and it is said The Page cannot be found

Comment: The path is correct tho.

Comment: Here is the exact path **/storage/promotion_images/Penguins_1543117560.jpg%20,%20Koala_1543117560.jpg**

Comment: How did you store images in the database ? json encoded or serialized data ?

Comment: @SagarGautam See my Code above I edited it.. I think it is serialized but im not familiar with it sir :(

Comment: @SummerWinter I've added my answer have a look if it works for you or not.

Comment: If your resource is assets folder then you can put directly like `{{'storage/promotion_images/' . $promotion->promotion_image}}`. And make sure that your object `$promotion->promotion_image` contains `image's extesion`. It should be like `storage/promotion_images/yourimage.jpg`. your image string may  looks like `storage/promotion_images/yourimage`. (without extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have done for storing images seems okay, what you have to do is explode the image data store in the database. So, change your view code like this:

```
@foreach($promotions as $promotion)
       <tr>  

        <th>
            @foreach(explode(',' ,$promotion->promotion_image) as $image)
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/promotion_images/' . $image) }}" style="width:50px;height:50px;"><br/>
            @endforeach
        </th>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

I think this will work for you. If you have any confusion regarding above code, feel free to ask.

Comment: SO CLOSE ... It stores 1 value ..  the other image is not available why is that

Comment: @SummerWinter Can you please describe it in more detail so that i might help you

Comment: I have a dynamic form using jquery and all images are stored in one ROW.. your code showed me 1 image only I have 2 images in a row in my database.. so the other 1 image is not shown in my view.

Comment: @SummerWinter please add the screenshot of the database table

Comment: hey sir can you answer this question of mine please [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468263/laravel-image-array-validation-gives-an-error-to-nullable-validate)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($promotion)) {
        $implodedPromotion = implode(' , ', $promotion);
        $promotionImage = new Promotion;
        $promotionImage->promotion_image = $implodedPromotion;
        $promotionImage->save();

        return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions',$promotion)->with('success', 'Image Inserted');
    }

    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions',$promotion)->with('error', 'Something went wrong.');
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: what's that? it doesnt seems to help me